# Python - Assigning vertex weights is extremely slow

Tags: python, vertex-weights

Current very slow method (code reduced):

```
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    vgroups = obj.vertex_groups.new(name="test_layer")

    for loop in obj.data.loops:
        vindex = obj.data.loops[loop.index].vertex_index
        vgroups.add([vindex], value, "REPLACE")
```

Performance is tested on 1024 x 1024 grid and takes minutes to complete for several weight layers.

My goal is not to assign the same weight value, but different values for each vertex.

I believe I am looking for something like below, which does not exist.

`active_object.vertex_groups[group_name].foreach_set()`

Comment: As noted in answer below, loop over verts not loops. 8 verts in cube, 24 loops.   Also content that `loop is obj.data.loops[loop.index]` in code above.

Comment: @batFINGER that is a good point, I did not think about that and will rewrite to use vertex index instead. I was using loops to get UV data for that vertex, but maybe even that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of loops here is not clear.

You can:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
vgroup = obj.vertex_groups.new(name="test_layer")

value = 0.5

for i in range(len(obj.data.vertices)):
    vgroup.add( [i], value, 'REPLACE')
```

We add vertices to a group, using their indexes.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.VertexGroup.html#bpy.types.VertexGroup.add):

> add(index, weight, type)
>
> ```
> Add vertices to the group
>
> Parameters
>         index (int array of 1 items in [-inf, inf]) – Index List
>         weight (float in [0, 1]) – Vertex weight
>         type (enum in ['REPLACE', 'ADD', 'SUBTRACT']) –
>         Vertex assign mode
>             REPLACE Replace, Replace.
>             ADD Add, Add.
>             SUBTRACT Subtract, Subtract.
> ```

Comment: I am using loops due to other processes in the function. The method you provided is the same one I use and is very slow. For example to batch set vertex colors this should work ```active_object.data.vertex_colors[0].data.foreach_set(new_color_set)```

Comment: OK. I tested what I propose on over a million of vertices, it is nearly instant (maybe 1s).

Comment: If you use data.loops and want to 'replace' the weight, you're just doing it several times. Why are you talking about vertex colors now?

Comment: No need for loop  with constant value  (`value = 0.5` as coded above) `vg.add(range(len(obj.data.vertices)),  value, 'REPLACE')`

Comment: @batFINGER. Sure but he ask for several values. "My goal is not to assign the same weight value, but different values for each vertex."

Comment: Yes can read. Maybe use `random()` or `zip` in example shown in answer  code. AFAIK there is no quick way to do `foreach_set / get` here. .

Comment: @batFINGER, yes but it is a bit unclear. In comments he's talking about vertex colors, now... so I don't know. And this is not so slow, so there is something elsewhere in the code that is slow.

Comment: I went to edit the comment to clarify, but missed the 5 minute time limit. I was just adding vertex_colors as an example. 1 second is better than what I am getting now, but is still slower than foreach_set would be unfortunately. On a 4k grid it would take 16 seconds and there are 5 vertex layers, so would take over a minute. I will rewrite my code to not use loops, that should help some.

Comment: @VSB, your question was about vertex groups, not colors. You can't foreach_set for groups.